# Java Servlets Overriding init(ServletConfig config)

Tags: java, servlets, init

I am trying to override init(ServletConfig config) method.My code is:

```
 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext(); // ----- NullPointerException
}
```

this is giving NullPointerException .

If i modify it as:

```
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext(); // ----- works fine
}
```

This works fine.
 I know that we should override init() method and not init(ServletConfig config) but
 Can anybody give me proper reason as why this is happening?

Comment: Where did you find that *we should override `init()` method and not `init(ServletConfig config)`*?

Comment: I am not saying that we cannot override init(ServletConfig config) method,we can, but i read that init() method is called internally from init(ServletConfig config) method, so we should override init() method.

Comment: It looks like you already have your answer. What else you need?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : But why NullpointerException is occuring?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compare the documentation for `init(ServletConfig)`:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException
Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet
is being placed into service.

See Servlet#init. This implementation stores the ServletConfig object
it receives from the servlet container for later use. When overriding
this form of the method, call super.init(config).
```

And compare that with the documentation for `init()`:

```
public void init() throws ServletException
A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need to
call super.init(config).

Instead of overriding init(ServletConfig), simply override this method
and it will be called by GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config). The
ServletConfig object can still be retrieved via getServletConfig().
```

When overriding `init(ServletConfig)`, the first thing that must be done is to call:

```
super.init(config);
```

If you do this then calling directly to `getServletContext()` in your method will no longer result in an NPE.

Comment: means after calling --  super.init(config);, servlet will get the reference to servletcontext?

Comment: @RiteshKaushik yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are overriding wrong method mechanism
If you overriding

```
     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
            ServletContext sc = getServletContext(); 
     }
```

Instead of overriding `init(ServletConfig)`, simply override the below method and it will be called by `GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config)`

```
 public void init() throws ServletException {
 ServletContext sc = getServletContext(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in :

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
}
```

you don't invoke `super.init(ServletConfig)`. As a result, ServletConfig is not stored in the servlet instance, and subsequent calls to getServletConfig will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the super init(config) at very first line of your overridden method

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
```